# break выход из цикла или всё-таки

Tags: java, switch, break

break - выбрасывает вас из цикла либо же ключевое слово которое выходит из цикла. Завершить цикл раньше времени и тд.

А вот у нас есть оператор switch и в нём так-то тоже пишут `break`, так почему везде пишут про то, что `break` всегда "выходит" из цикла?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Не знаю почему «везде» так пишут, но в спецификации Java про break написано точно ([§14.15 The break Statement](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.15)):

> A break statement with no label attempts to transfer control to the innermost enclosing **switch, while, do, or for** statement of the immediately enclosing method or initializer; this statement, which is called the break target, then immediately completes normally.
>
> *Инструкция break без метки пытается передать управление наиболее глубоко вложенной охватывающей инструкции **switch, while, do или for** непосредственно охватывающего блока или инициализатора; затем эта инструкция, которая называется целевой, немедленно завершается нормально.*

Также в спецификации описывается вариант break с указанием метки, который может вывеcти из любой охватывающей инструкции (не только наиболее глубокой).

Answer (score 2):

В Java оператор `break` (один из операторов "перехода") действительно используется как в циклах, так и в конструкции оператора switch. В циклах, при наступлении определенного условия, этот оператор прерывает выполнение, пропускается остальной код в теле цикла и происходит передача управления на оператор, следующий за циклом. Внутри последовательности операторов в конструкции switch оператор break также используется для прерывания данной последовательности. Как только выполняется условие в операторе case, "срабатывает" `break` и, аналогично циклам, управление передается на оператор, следующий за конструкцией `switch`. Следует отметить, что в конструкции `switch` наличие оператора `break` не является обязательным. При его отсутствии программа продолжит выполнение со следующим оператором `case`, например, при необходимости проверки выполнения не одного, а ряда условий выраженных в нескольких операторах `case`.

```
class BreakExample {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        for(int i=0; i<6; i++)
        switch(i) {
            case 0:
            case 1:
            case 2:
                System.out.println("Значение i=" + 
                    i +  " и это меньше 3");
                break;
            case 3:
            case 4:
            case 5:
                System.out.println("Значение i=" + 
                    i + " и это больше 2, но меньше 6");
                break;
        }
    }
}
```